# Laravel formulario en blade

Tags: html, laravel, formularios, botón, blade

Mirando códigos en Internet he encontrado un formulario en una vista blade como el siguiente:

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('grabar') }}">
    @csrf
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{ $user->id }}">
    <button class="btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm">Enviar</button>
</form>
```

Lo he probado y funciona. Y mi pregunta es ¿Por qué funciona? El botón no es `submit`, sino un botón sin acción específica asignada (no hay un javascript que lea el evento de pulsarlo, ni nada así), y en cambio actúa enviando el formulario. Se supone que debería ser un botón de tipo `submit` para que lo enviase, no? Por qué envía el formulario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según la especificación de HTML, al no especificar nada en el atributo type (tipo), el comportamiento predeterminado del botón es `type="submit"`.

> A button element with no type attribute specified represents the same thing as a button element with its type attribute set to "submit".

Una traducción aproximada al español sería:

> Un elemento button sin el atributo type especificado representa lo mismo que un elemento button con el atributo type asignado a "submit".

Puedes ver la documentación en los siguientes enlaces:

http://w3c.github.io/html-reference/button.html

https://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/the-button-element.html#the-button-element

Comment: No conocía esto. Es bueno saber que es un comportamiento previsto, no accidental.